# How to integrate Spring application with Mule ESB

Tags: spring, mule

I want to integrate my spring (3.0) application with Mule ESB (Mule3) and make available those service for different clients (.Net, GWT etc). For accomplish this, whether I should deploy my Spring application as separate component and define Endpoint on Mule or I can deploy my spring application inside the Mule and provide those services to outside clients. If anyone know some ideas or any sample reference projects related to this problem, can please update me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend integrating Mule into your Spring application.   That is, adding the Mule jar files to your app and using it as a library.   Doing it this way Mule adds a child context to your main Spring application context and has access to your beans so they can be used as services.

The [Using Mule with Spring](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Using+Mule+with+Spring) and [Spring Application Contexts](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Spring+Application+Contexts) pages are the places to start learning about how to do this.