# Spring to Mule ESB integration sample

Tags: spring, mule, mule-studio

I have implemented the ESB activities in Mule ESB, and now i need to integrate the spring application with MULE esb,so tried few blog for integration sample but didn't get clear picture of integration sample, can any do share the site for integration sample.

Answer (score 1):

Hope these links help:

[How to integrate Spring application with Mule ESB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426131/how-to-integrate-spring-application-with-mule-esb)

http://www.mulesoft.com/resources/esb/mule-esb-best-choice-spring-integration

Comment: Hi @learner, i have tried this sites but couldn't able to make the successful integration and am fresher to spring, can suggest any sample code or example for the integration.

Comment: i have tried [Single Application Context](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Spring+Application+Contexts)  but it throws `Exception in thread "main" org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name '_mulePropertyPlaceholderProcessor' defined in URL [jar:file:/F:/mule-standalone-3.3.1/lib/mule/mule-module-spring-config-3.3.1.jar!/mule-spring-config.xml]:'